# Is it possible to uncheck “Print to File” from QPrinter dialog called from QPrintDialog?

Tags: python, pyside2

I am trying to print a pdf file using QPrinterDialog, and disable the "Print To File" option in dialog.

There are methods to enable/disable this option, but not to uncheck it.
Is it possible to uncheck this option pragmatically using qt framework?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>It seems that the "Print to file" option only appears if you have a printer connected but at the moment I do not have it so my solution is not tested.</sub>

One possible solution is to filter the children of the window with the name of the text to obtain the QCheckBox:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
    dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog(printer)

    def on_timeout():
        for checkbox in dialog.findChildren(QtWidgets.QCheckBox):
            print(
                "objectName: {}, text: {}".format(
                    checkbox.objectName(), checkbox.text()
                )
            )
            if checkbox.text() == "Print to file":
                checkbox.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, on_timeout)

    if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(printer)
        painter.fillRect(printer.pageRect(), QtGui.QColor("salmon"))
```